# C# Close any application running in System Tray

Tags: c#, system-tray

I want to properly close any application (not kill) running in system tray. I have tried SendKeys() but it fails. Sending <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> then x all fail because tray applications have no main window. Any idea how to do that? the objective to to properly exit an application that performs some inner tasks upon exiting, running in system tray without terminating, just like when its titlebar exit button is clicked.

Comment: First entry in google: https://alanbondo.wordpress.com/2008/06/22/creating-a-system-tray-app-with-c/

Comment: @McNets That's how to write a tray application, not to close *other* ones.

Comment: Do you want to close other apps than yours?

Comment: Killing someone else application, which maybe is just sitting there displaying itself, or maybe is controlling the cooling system in a nuclear plant, is considered really impolite.

Comment: Well mannered notification area applications will offer a means for closing them through a context menu. But they are by no means *forced* to offer such a function. There's no standard function to trigger a close from the icon.

Comment: @McNets Yes exactly, i want to close third party apps, not mine.

Comment: @GianPaolo actually that third party application i am using for myself, i am running it and i want to properly quit it.

Comment: If you know what the app is (because _I am using for myself_), then why not find that process using the `Process` class and close it that way?  If it's written properly, it should also remove the icon.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer to this. Each and every application has its own way of controlling life time. You can even write Forms application that does not respond to `[Alt F4]` to shut it down.

The only way you can an arbitrary process of which you know nothing (other than that it has put an icon into the system tray), is to terminate the process. And that, as Gian Paolo pointed out, is just not cricket.

Comment: Ok let me put it this way... i have an application which saves its status upon exit. Upon restart, it resumes from the saved state. if it is terminated forcibly, it rebuilds its cache upon startup and that takes a very long time. i start the application when system starts, and quit it manually just before shutdown/restart. i dont want to do that everytime i logout or shutdown or restart, thats why i want to write a program to close it gracefully through scheduled tasks on shutdown/restart/logout etc.

Comment: Then you need to find out for each and every one of these applications what the shutdown mechanism peculiar to that process is and invoke it. But, if you don't have any documentation on the process that tells you how to do that, you are back to using the sledge hammer and smash it by terminating the process. It's a bit like asking "How do I open any door I might come across, even if I don't have the key for it?"

Comment: so its a dead end then?

Answer (score 0):

From what you have written on the comments on the other answers, it sounds like you merely want to close a specific app. You can do this with the [`taskkill`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725602(WS.10).aspx) utility.